# Facebook Ad insight GRAPH API edge for a date range

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to get Facebook Ad stats for a given date range using Facebook Graph API. It doesn't seem to work.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/6039003162091/insights?since=2016-03-14&until=2016-03-15&access_token=<>

Any idea how I should go about with this?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the comments above and adding it here so it is clear. The issue was in the format of the time_range parameter as it needs to be

```
time_range={"since":"2016‌​-03-15","until":"2016-03-15"}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_id?fields=ads{insights.time_range({"since":"2016-03-14","until":"2016-04-15"})}&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

if you want day by day data you can alter as

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/6039003162091?fields=ads{insights.time_range({"since":"2016-03-14","until":"2016-04-15"}).time_increment(1)}&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN