# DatePeriod for Facebook Ads Insights API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, filter, date-range

I am able to get Facebook Campaign Insights using the marketing API, but I can only get it for a said period of time. The code below gives data for last 30 days. How can I get a dropdown to get data for user input period (eg. 60days or 1 day or 1 week etc). Please let me know the code.
As per developers site, available presets:
date_preset
enum{today, yesterday, last_3_days, this_week, last_week, last_7_days, last_14_days, last_28_days, last_30_days, last_90_days, this_month, last_month, this_quarter, last_3_months, lifetime}

```
$params = array (
    'date_preset'=>'last_30_days',
    'data_columns'=>"['adgroup_id','actions','reach']",
);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the time range field. For example `time_range={"since":"2016‌​-03-15","until":"2016-03-15"}` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013472/facebook-ad-insight-graph-api-edge-for-a-date-range/36014467#36014467)